# Is there any difference between the Kubernetes python client and regular Python?

Tags: python, kubernetes

I’m building an App that runs on K8s version 1.21 and the container already includes Python 3.92.  Do I still need to install https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python  if I want to interact with Kubernetes using Python or am I good?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes Python client is the library that helps you interact with [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.22/).

So if you want to do anything with Kubernetes API from inside your Python program (e.g. query the currently running Pods), then you need to install Kubernetes python client.

However, if your application is just deployed in Kubernetes, but does not need interact with Kubernetes API, then you don't need it.

Comment: So, I think what your telling me is that my Python 3.9 already in the running Pod will not help me interact with the Kubernetes API?

Comment: yes, that's right

Answer (score 0):

Would like more info on what are planning to do. If you going to just run Python programs then you don't need this library at all. This is for accessing Kubernetes (K8S) REST APIs.Also even for REST API you can do normal REST API calls and handle Requests/Responses or take help from this library for doing the heavy lifting. Whether python is running outside or inside a container or pod, you need the library for accessing REST APIs to do specific API functionalities not related to actual python to work.
Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/

Comment: I'm running a ML app that interacts with Spark.  There are two images.  The first is the Spark driver, which is the one I need to interact with K8s.  The next image, which uses the first, is a Python app which includes Python 3.9.  I wasn't sure I needed to add the the Python library in the first image to interact with K8 since I already have Python running in the second image.  I decided to add this additional library.  Hope it all works. I think the confusion for me is that they just call this library Python and I'm guessing it's more than that!

Comment: Hi Reid, it is just to call kubernetes REST API, what kind of calls your first image will do to K8S?